Smoothing spatial data for privacy issues
I have a dataset with about 6000 observations related to municipalities.
The structure of the dataset includes four columns: the municipality code, the number of businesses in the municipality, the number of businesses with at least n employees, and the percentage of the latter on the total.
Since some municipalities are very small, there are observations for which the percentage is 0 or 100.
Because I need to make this dataset public, I need to get rid of these 0s and 100s without losing the observations. Therefore, I should apply some spatial smoothing algorithm.
I tried using spatial moving average, but it distorts the results too much (if a municipality with 3000 businesses is a neighbor of a municipality with 0 businesses, the SMA is too distortive).
How could I get rid of the 0s and 1s without distorting (too much) the data of the other municipalities? What algorithm could I use?
The dataset is linked to a shapefile through the municipality code.
Thanks.

are you dead-set on not losing observations? Because combining multiple small municipalities into one, or folding a small municipality into a neighboring big municipality would be a friendly solution in that it avoids making specific assumptions about the data-generating process, the types of analyses you want to conduct, or the type of attacks you want to protect against.

outside of binning, which would be my first approach, you could take a look at the differential privacy methods that were used in the 2020 census
